# Flutter Secure Storage Fails to Read From A Key That Exists

Tags: flutter, dart, local-storage

I have a simple function that reads from local storage.

```
  Future<String> getLastTimeLoginMessageWasSeen(String datasource, String username) async {
    String date;
    try {
      var debug = await localStorage.readAll();
      debugPrint('READ ALL: ${debug.toString()}');
      date = await localStorage.read(key: '_time_$datasource²$username');
    } catch (e) {
      Client.postErrorLog(
          section: "Uploads", action: "UploadsPage.getLastTimeLoginMessageWasSeen", exception: e.toString());
    }
    return date;
  }
```

My problem is that date is always null here. I added a debug statement to ensure that the key I am trying to read exists and it does. I don't understand why it fails to read from the key. If I execute the same read function in my store method, it reads successfully.

```
storeLastTimeLoginMessageWasSeen(String username, String datasource) async {
    try {
      await localStorage.write(key: '_time_$datasource²$username', value: DateTime.now().toString());
      String date = await localStorage.read(key: '_time_$datasource²$username');
      debugPrint('READ LAST SAVED TIME: $date');
    } catch (e) {
      Client.postErrorLog(section: 'Uploads', action: 'Uploads.storeLastTimeLoginMessageWasSeen');
    }
  }
```

Since the read function works fine elsewhere, I feel like I have made a mistake in my getLastTimeMessageWasSeen method. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Why does your key contain... unusual characters like `²` instead of using _normal_ separator characters?

Comment: I dont think it matters. Just a delimeter. It what others were using in the project and I wanted to remain consistent.

Comment: **It does matter** (or at least, it _can_ matter) because your saved Flutter file might be using a different encoding or (more likely) is denormalized Unicode, which means the actual bytes representing the string are different even if the displayed glyphs are the same. There's lots of obscure Unicode and encoding-related bugs to be found when using non-ASCII characters in key/value storage systems.

Comment: Thats interesting and good to know, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here. Just tested it.

Comment: Okay - at least that potential cause can be eliminated. Though I wonder if the issue is your use of string-interpolation. What happens if you use explicit string concatenation - or use `${}` to delimit identifiers instead of having "naked" variables in the key strings?

Comment: I note that using `DateTime.now().toString()` means you'll be storing a culture-sensitive formatted value that won't be read correctly if the user changes their culture settings and then restarts your program (e.g. if they're set to `en-US` then today's date would be saved as `3/10/2021` but if they change to `en-GB` then that would be read-back as October 3rd, 2021, which is incorrect. You should use `toIso8601String()` if you're saving date+time values as text.